# How can I open up chrome programatically from the bash shell?

Tags: macos, bash, google-chrome

I've learned how to kill it by simply using

`pkill Chrome`

but how do I open it in bash in OS X ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the full path of open as bash already knows where to find this.

It also knows where to find Chrome.

However you do need the full path of Chrome:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args 'gmail.com'
```

Comment: You shouldn't need "/Applications/" either... try just "Google Chrome" or "Google Chrome.app".

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$ open -a "Google Chrome"
```

or

```
$ open -a Google\ Chrome
```

More information:

```
$ manx open
```

Comment: thanks why does this not work - `open -a "Firefox.app"` ... should be the same correct ?

Comment: It works for me... and you shouldn't need to include the extension, since you're telling the open command that it's an app with the `-a` option.

Comment: ...you missed the args though ... ILLILI

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/usr/bin/open -a` command to run your browser.
adding `--args`  will open the browser from the command line and go to the target URL

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args 'http://google.com/'
```

Comment: are you there ... also, the --args works on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not **Safari** as Safari prepends it with `file://` breaking any URLs.  How can I get this to work for Safari ?

Comment: Sorry, went offline.  Safari is a bit weirder.  `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari & sleep 1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.google.com"'`