# Why doesn't --args work for Safari?

Tags: macos, bash, safari

```
#Safari is Dumb

birthBrowsers(){
    open -a "Google Chrome" --args 'gmail.com'
    open -a "Firefox" --args 'gmail.com'
    open -a "Safari" --args 'https://mail.google.com'
    open -a "Opera" --args 'gmail.com'    
}
```

I tried domain.com, www.domain.com and finally `http://www.domain.com`

but it kept adding `file:///` , yes with 3 forward slashes

in front causing a fail.  How do I fix ...

Was working on this solution which prompted desire to know.

[How can I open up chrome programatically from the bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144616)

Comment: `file:///` is the correct prefix for a local system file. `file://` like `http://` and then `/` for the start of the "path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the "`--args`" bit.

Try using:

```
open -a "Safari" https://mail.google.com
```

The answer for which I found [in this duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/459268/run-safari-from-command-line-with-url-parameter) from StackOverflow's sister site.